# Как добавить текст через js в html

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно в пустой элемент p с классом country вставить текст через js. Такой код почему то не работает:

```
<p class="country"></p>

var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('country');
elem.innerHTML = "USA";
document.body.appendChild(elem);
```

И такой тоже

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('country');
var textElem = document.createTextNode('USA');
elem.appendChild(textElem);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). Метод getElementsByClassName возвращает как видно из названия (elements - множественное число) array-like объект, а не конкретный элемент DOM.

Как получаем доступ к элементу массива?

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('country'); 
elem[0].innerHTML = "USA"
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать)

Answer (score 2):

Вы обращаетесь к классу, по этому правильно будет:

```
elem[0].innerHTML = "text";
```

Ваш код будет корректно работать при обращении к id.
Пример:

```
HTML: <p id="country"></p>
var elem = document.getElementById('country');
elem.innerHTML = "text";
```